# Trouble creating an expanding list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, parent-child

I need to make a list for my client's podcast archive page that opens up to reveal links to the different podcasts for the month they click on. I pretty much want exactly something like BlogSpot has for their default blog archive widget on the right side of the page here: http://kimrome.blogspot.com/

I was able to make something like that here: http://thehummingbirdplace.com/test2.html but I'm not sure how to make the arrows that show if a list has been expanded or not. So it needs to change direction when it's clicked and return to the previous direction when it's clicked again to close that section.

My version also has the child elements showing when I open the page, and I don't want them to expand until their parent is clicked on.

I've look online to see if there is jQuery already created to do this, or how I might be able to make it, but since I'm not sure what this whole thing is properly titled, I get mixed results. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What you are looking for is an accordion. Accordion menus are fairly straightforward to create using jQuery. There are plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: You can also look into [**Jquery EasyUI Tree**](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/?plugin=Tree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=) plugin. Check out the **Async Tree** demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to do this yourself (it's fun to write things yourself):

I've added an ID of `#tree` to the root `<ul>`, and wrapped the text of the level 1 `<li>`s in `<span>`:

```
<ul id="tree">
    <li>
        <span>parent1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>child11</li>
            <li>child12</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>parent2</span>
        <ul>
            <li>child21</li>
            <li>child22</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To apply arrows that point left and right to the parent elements, create two CSS classes with backgrounds, for example (you'll need to find the background images elsewhere or make your own):

```
.opened > span {
    background: url('arrow_pointing_down.png') left top;
    color: #0a0; /* just to make it easy to know which class it has */
}
.closed > span {
  background: url('arrow_pointing_right.png') right top;
    color: #00a; /* just to make it easy to know which class it has */
}
```

To hide all the child elements when the page loads...

```
$('#tree > li').addClass('closed');
// hide the level 2 ul's
$('#tree > li ul').hide();
```

Then in your click handler:

```
$("#tree > li > span").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // swap the opened and closed classes
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('opened closed');
     // toggle the level 2 ul instead of li
    $(this).parent().find("ul").toggle();
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cTLGN/

---

**ADDITIONAL:**

This demo code doesn't make use of caching references to jQuery objects to make it easier to read. In reality instead of doing:

```
$(this).parent().toggleClass('opened closed');
$(this).parent().find("ul").toggle();
```

... one should do:

```
var parent = $(this).parent(); // search the DOM once for this' parent, and remember it
parent.toggleClass('opened closed');
parent.find("ul").toggle();
```

.. because every time you use jQuery's $() constructor it needs to search thru the entire DOM, which can be quite expensive if you do it repeatedly.

Comment: I like the idea of writing it myself, but when I tried your suggestion, everything disappeared because the .hide() is applying to the parent element too, I also couldn't get the arrows to show up (I made my own for it to use)

Comment: Updated answer, see fiddle for working demo. Feel free to modify the CSS to change the appearance, or modify the Javascript to accommodate more nested layers if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery-UI [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

```
$(...).accordion();
```

, or this: http://jsfiddle.net/5SKLV/1/

```
$(...).myAccordion();
```

Just write CSS at your taste.

Comment: @StefanDunn, your idea is brilliant!

Comment: Thanks, although it's not supported in < IE9 so it's only really a modern browser fallback.

Comment: I really do not care about IE. Let's Balmer is using it, not me.

Comment: Let's force a redirect for IE users to Chrome's download page :)

Comment: I love the sliding aspect of this and @StefanDunn's CSS fallback is genius, but for my site's needs, jingtao's solution was best. Thank you for the help!